# ¿Por qué no puedo utilizar un "setter" para establecer el valor de un atributo cuando he instanciado como un vector?

Tags: java, poo

**Aquí va a lo que me refiero: (Este código me da error)**

```
public class PruebaPOO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Multimedia imagenes[] = new Multimedia[5];

        imagenes[1].setNombre("leon"); //Aquí me produce el error
        imagenes[1].setTamaño(20);

        System.out.println(imagenes[1]);
        //System.out.println(imagenes[2]);

    }

}
```

**Esta es la clase Multimedia:**

```
public class Multimedia {

    private String nombre;
    private int tamaño;

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getTamaño(){
        return this.tamaño;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setTamaño(int tamaño){
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "nombre : " + nombre + " / peso : " + tamaño;
    }

}
```

**Por lo contrario esto sí me funciona:**

```
public class PruebaPOO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Multimedia imagenes[] = new Multimedia[5];

        imagenes[1] = new Multimedia("leon", 20);

        System.out.println(imagenes[1]);
        //System.out.println(imagenes[2]);

    }

}

public class Multimedia {

    private String nombre;
    private int tamaño;

    Multimedia(String nombre, int tamaño){

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tamaño = tamaño;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "nombre : " + nombre + " / peso : " + tamaño;
    }

}
```

**Me da como resultado:** nombre : leon / peso : 20
(Que es lo que espero del primer programa.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buenas al igual que en el segundo caso debes instanciar el objeto. Es decir en tu primer caso (el que no funciona) debes hacer

```
imagenes[1] = new Multimedia();
imagenes[1].setNombre("Juan") ;
imagenes[1].setTamaño(20);
```

por lo contrario, estarás intentando acceder a un método de un objeto que es igual a null. Toda clase por defecto tiene un constructor vacío (excepto que tu declares alguno), es por esto que puedes hacer new Multimedia() aunque no esté explícito en la clase.

Cuando haces

```
  Multimedia imágenes[5] = new Multimedia[5];
```

simplemente estás creando un vector que referencia a 5 instancias Multimedia, por defecto estas instancias son igual a null. Las debes inicializar cada una.

**Actualización**

En Java, el índice arranca en 0 y no en 1. Por lo tanto, en un vector de tamaño 5, el índice va desde 0 - 4 (5 elementos en total). Si intentas acceder con  **indice = 5** (objeto número seis: `imagenes[5]`) te va a tirar una excepción indicando que estas por fuera del array.

Asi que si buscas completar tu array desde el principio recuerda arrancar siempre desde 0.

```
imagenes[0] = new Multimedia(); //primer elemento
imagenes[1] = new Multimedia(); //segundo elemento
imagenes[2] = new Multimedia(); //tercer elemento
imagenes[3] = new Multimedia(); //cuarto elemento
imagenes[4] = new Multimedia(); //quinto elemento
imagenes[5] = new Multimedia(); //error indice fuera de rango!!
```

Comment: Seria bueno que le explicaras que los array comienzan desde cero y no del indice 1.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, se me ha pasado por alto. Gracias!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!! Ya lo entendí